# How to change the default value of Grid page size in Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I am new to Kendo UI. i have my code as follows.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ETS.Model.CompanyList>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyID).Title("Name").Template(@<text>@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "Company", "Companies", new { @id = @item.CompanyID }, new { @style = "color:black; text-decoration: none;" })</text>);
        columns.Bound(p => p.City).Title("Billing City");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SalesRep).Title("Sales Rep");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Phone).Title("Company Name");
    })
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
         .PageSizes(true)
         .ButtonCount(5)
         .Refresh(true)
    )
    .Sortable()                       
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: auto;" })
    .BindTo(Model.Companies)
)
```

By default the there are 5 items displayed on the grid. Is there any way i can change that default value to 20 ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally you would set the using the [`PageSize()` function](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#pagesize) on your `DataSource` :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Product>()
    .Name("grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax() 
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
        .PageSize(20)
    )
)
```

or you could try limiting the available [`PageSizes()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#pagesizes) to just 20 :

```
.Pageable(pageable => pageable.PageSizes(new int[] {20}) ...)
```

Additionally, it can be set through the Javascript API via :

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.pageSize(20);
grid.refresh();
```

Comment: Your answer let me change the value of the pages but it didnt set 20 as a default value. The value is 20 in the box but only 5 items are displayed.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting a DataSource and using `.DataSource(ds => ds.Server().PageSize(20))` to see if that made a difference?

Comment: What about initializing it via the default JSON initializer: `var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({ ... });` ... isn't there a parameter for this purpose?